# Is the sentence "В комнату вошла женщина и мальчик" grammatically correct?

Tags: грамматика

I'll respect each and every opinion. Today, I saw professionals opting for the following variant:

> В комнату вошла женщина и мальчик.

They say it's totally correct because женщина is a feminine singular noun.
But is this in fact true (and if so, why)?

Comment: where you've seen this professionals? - and what exactly kind professionals? - this is just not correct and a very strange thing to claim

Comment: According to Розенталь it is correct, but the rule is not very strict, so both variants are possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it needs to agree in number.

В комнату вошл**и** женщина и мальчик. The subjects are женщина и мальчик, therefore the verb needs to be in the plural. A woman and a boy (jointly) entered the room.

Or perhaps you meant: В комнату вошла женщина *с мальчиком*. A woman *with* a boy entered the room. Here the boy isn't the subject.

Or perhaps you meant: В комнату вошла женщина, и с ней **—** мальчик. (Compare https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428641 ) Here the em-dash stands the verb *вошёл*, omitted before *мальчик*.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct, but I could imagine it being used to deliberately stress the insignificance of the boy - perhaps to be refuted later in the story.

Comment: It would jar my ear for sure.